# Apache Web Server (httpd) - Files over proxy pass

Tags: apache, webserver

I have an `Apache httpd` setup with `VirtualHost`

I am doing some `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` so I can redirect calls to a local server.

What I want is to have the ability to mock some endpoints with files on the apache server if they exist.

So for example I have the endpoint

`http://localhost:8080/myapp/myendpoint`

and now when I run

`http://localhost/myapp/myendpoint`

apache with my `VirtualHost` setup redirects the calls to my local server

Now lets say I put a file in `{apache main dir}/htdocs/myapp/` called `myendpoint` .

If I remove the `Location` tag with `ProxyPass` in `VirtualHost` calling

`http://localhost/myapp/myendpoint`  returns the results of the file in htdocs. But if I leave the above `Location` tag in the configuration it ignores the file and goes to the server.

How can I configure `Apache Web Server` to give priority to the file before doing the proxypass?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ProxyPass         /localhost/myapp/ http://localhost:8080/localhost/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse  /localhost/myapp/ http://localhost:8080/localhost/myapp/
```

You can try with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule       /localhost/myapp/ http://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
ProxyPassReverse  /localhost/myapp/ http://localhost:8080/localhost/myapp/
```

(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p, notice the Performance warning)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Indeed if I remove the ProxyPass it works but not properly as instead of proxying the request it responds with a 302 redirect which does matter if the client is not a browser. Any other way to do it? (Also I do not care about the performance hit as it is only for local development)